# Hibernate CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy incorrectly maps column with capatalized single trailing character

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

**spring-boot 3.1.0 / Hibernate 6.2.2**

```
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy
#spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.hibernate.SpringImplicitNamingStrategy
```

You can toggle the above but the result stays the same. (or leave it out for the default SpringImplicitNamingStrategy)

Entity with attribute: `private issueD` and DB column: `issue_d` gets mapped to a query with target `r1_0.issued`.

resulting in an exception(condensed):

`ERROR: column r1_0.issued does not exist Hint: Perhaps you meant to reference the column "r1_0.issue_d".`

All other columns work properly.

I can't find any docs on this. Any ideas?

I am renaming the column/attribute to `issued_at/issuedAt` in the meantime.

Comment: IDK what is your question !! It's normal behavior that hibernate maps issueD to issue_d, any uppercase letter(except for first letter) will be replaced with (_lowerCaseLetter)  A -> _a , D -> _d

Comment: @AhmedNabil... excuse me?! Maybe i must be more clear? - "Entity with attribute: private issueD and DB column: issue_d gets mapped to a query with target r1_0.issued."

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is in the source code of `CamelCaseToUnderscoresNamingStrategy`:

```java
private Identifier apply(final Identifier name, final JdbcEnvironment jdbcEnvironment) {
    if ( name == null ) {
        return null;
    }
    StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder( name.getText().replace( '.', '_' ) );
    for ( int i = 1; i < builder.length() - 1; i++ ) {
        if ( isUnderscoreRequired( builder.charAt( i - 1 ), builder.charAt( i ), builder.charAt( i + 1 ) ) ) {
            builder.insert( i++, '_' );
        }
    }
    return getIdentifier( builder.toString(), name.isQuoted(), jdbcEnvironment );
}
```

As you see the logic evaluated all the characters apart from the last one, i.e. the part of the identifier will be separated with underscore only if it is of length 2 and more.

P.S. If you want to keep `issueD` name you should implement Hibernate's `PhysicalNamingStrategy` interface and use it in your `application.properies`.

Comment: Thanks! Yes sure, but why stop one short? Any reason for that? I am quite happy with the behavior otherwise. I just have to make a new entry into the acceptable namingConventions.

Comment: I don't know, perhaps it's about implementation of `isUnderscoreRequired()` requiring three chars, so you couldn't evaluate the last one separately.